# Does DispatchQueue also Lock the resources used inside it?

Tags: swift, thread-safety, dispatch-queue, nslock

```
class Factory {
  var localSharedResource
  var localQueue =  DispatchQueue(label: "localQueue")
  let threadLock = NSLock()

  func modify(){
    localQueue.async {
      self.threadLock.lock() 
      localSharedResource = "a change is made here"
      self.threadLock.unlock()
    }
  }
}
```

Should I use lock if localSharedResource is accessed by other threads too?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If all access to `localSharedResource` is wrapped via a `localQueue.sync` or `localQueue.async`, then the `threadLock` property can be removed. The serial queue (`localQueue`) is already doing all the necessary synchronization. The above could be rewritten as:

```
class Factory {
  var localSharedResource
  var localQueue =  DispatchQueue(label: "localQueue")

  func modify(){
    localQueue.async {
      localSharedResource = "a change is made here"
    }
  }
}
```

If however there are multiple threads potentially accessing the `localSharedResource` and `localQueue` is one of them, then the `localSharedResource` needs to have additional means of synchronization. Either by an `NSLock` or by using a dedicated serial queue.

E.g.

```
class Factory {
  var localSharedResource
  var localQueue =  DispatchQueue(label: "localQueue")
  let threadLock = NSLock()

  func modify(){
    localQueue.async {
      self.threadLock.lock() 
      localSharedResource = "a change is made here"
      self.threadLock.unlock()
    }
  }
  
  func modifyAgain() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
      self.threadLock.lock()
      localSharedResource = "another change"
      self.threadLock.unlock()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Does a simple lock work? I am a bit confuses if the way you are proposing actually locks the resource. Should the lock go to the getter of the property? 2. Does lock need to exist to every place this resource is accessed? Or using it only in modify does lock it for everybody?

Comment: So to rephrase my question. Lock doesnt lock resources, it locks code block lines, right? Wrapping lock around a resource doen’t lock the resource everywhere

Comment: Correct, to synchronize access to the `localSharedResource`, it needs to be wrapped either by the locking code or via a serial queue. This needs to happen every time `localSharedResource` is accessed or modified.